Plotting a cell's value in sheets as if another cell is changing
I have a spreadsheet with some calculations in it, and I want to make a plot of what happens to one cell's value as another changes (from 0 to 100). I have been searching for about 45 minutes and cant find any addons or functions that achieve this. It is not practical to make a copy of the data for every step because there are a bunch of interim calculations that rely on the value.
Is this possible easily, or do I need to restructure my spreadsheet to make 100 copies of the formulas?
Here is a simplified version, I want to plot the value of J2 as A2 changes from 0 to 100. The formulas are not exact, as the real sheet is significantly more complex, but it is the same idea.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nGx0smnBU8J9MU4wlKStSgPe2poVIvYENevvnG1a5AY

Would you be able to provide your sample sheet, with your initial output, and also your expected output so that we can further help you. You may use this to provide a markdown table (you may create one with the help of this link ) or an anonymous sample spreadsheet (using this link)

Give me a minute, I will make a simplified version that doesnt have sensitive info in it.

Can you provide your expected output by using a markdown table?

Not sure exactly what you're asking for, the output would be a graphical chart plotting the relation between two arbitrary cells but the expected data for the first few results is in the sheet. Obviously I happened to pick a boring relation between them with my formulas, but the real sheet is much more complicated, not that it matters because the interim steps are not relevant to the question.

Could you elaborate on the details of your question or provide more information about your sheets? I still don't seem to understand what you wanted to achieve.

Are you open to use App Script instead?

One "input" cell influences the value of a different "output" cell (through multiple calculations). I want to create a graph (bar chart, scatter plot, whatever you want) that has the output values on the y axis and a simulated range of inputs on the x axis. I cannot easily make 100 formula to spit out 100 values so I can plot them like that, I need it to be automated. If there isnt the functionality built in (dont think there is) then I am open to using a script even if it just bruteforces it and creates N cells somewhere automatically to plot. @LimeHusky

Given the sheets provided. Yes, you can create automation using App Script.

@yuuuu, Is your diff the output of your input?

@LimeHusky the formula was changed, that was the output of J2 for the input values of A2 before, now the outputs are different.

Plotting Cells using Sheet Formula
I created a solution using Sheet Formula based on your spreadsheet.
How the Formula Works

Cell A2 contains the input that specifies the number of outputs to be calculated.

Formula:
=LET(a,SEQUENCE(A2 + 1),b,BYROW(a,LAMBDA(x,(((x-1)*D3/5)+C3)-(((x-1)*D5/3)+C5))),c,BYROW(a,LAMBDA(y,y-1)),HSTACK(c,b))

Input: 10



input
diff




0
-14


1
2.666666667


2
19.33333333


3
36


4
52.66666667


5
69.33333333


6
86


7
102.6666667


8
119.3333333


9
136


10
152.6666667



Reference:

LET
SEQUENCE
BYROW
LAMBDA
HSTACK


